# Getting a warning when trying to use CV to find optimal M for random forest

Tags: r

This is the warning: Warning: 'length(x) = 5 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

Using the Carseats dataset in ISLR2.

I made these training sets:

```
Carseats$High <- factor(ifelse(Carseats$Sales <=8, "No", "Yes"))
train <- sample(1:nrow(Carseats), 200)
Carseats.test <- Carseats[-train, ]
Carseats.train <- Carseats[train,]
```

Then used this to cross-validate:

```
m = seq(2, 10, by = 2)
cv.results <- cv.out <- randomForest(High ~ ., data = Carseats.train, mtry = m, ntree = 500, importance = TRUE, cv = 5)
optimalM =  cv_results$mtry[which.min(cv_results$err.rate[])]
optimalM
```

Am I getting this error because I'm not supposed to be using cv out for a random forest?

I'm new to R so I know this is probably an easy fix. Thanks

Comment: `randomForest` expects `mtry` to be a single value, not a vector of values. If you want to try out different `mtry` values, you'll need to fit a separate model for each value and compare. Or use a package like `caret` that wraps up hyperparameter tuning in other functions.

Comment: I'd also note that, [in the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.7-1.1/topics/randomForest), there's no argument named `cv`, so `cv = 5` isn't doing anything.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you I figured it out with just a simple for loop